# Вывести не повторяющиеся элементы массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть простой массив

```
$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 1, 5, 7, 1);
```

Как вывести только все уникальные не повторяющиеся значения? Т.е. на выходе должно быть 2, 5, 3, 1, 7

Использовать функцию array_unique($arr) нельзя.

Comment: Если именно `вывести только все уникальные не повторяющиеся значения` то ссылка на дубликат выше ↑

Comment: Алексей, посмотрел дубликат по вашей ссылке. Но Pyramidhead ниже предложил другое хорошее решение.

Comment: В его решении просто убираются лишние дубли...а `не повторяющиеся уникальные элементы` в твоем массиве это 3 и 7..... хотя, возможно, ты и имел в виду всё же тот вариант а не этот........ двоякая формулировка получилась просто

Comment: да, я имел ввиду лишние дубли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$arr = array(2, 5, 5, 3 ,2, 1, 5, 7, 1);
$uniq_arr = array();
foreach ($arr AS $item) {
    if (!in_array($item, $uniq_arr)) {
        $uniq_arr[] = $item;
        echo $item . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: отличное решение! Небольшой код. Спасибо !

Comment: можно использовать `array_count_values()` или вдобавок к нему `array_filter()`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю особенности языка php. Но если создать новый массив `var unique = [];`
и в цикле проверять содержится ли элемент в src, что-то наподобии `$arr.contains(_ell);` если не содержится то добавлять в массив **unique**.

Насчет синтаксиса функции которая проверит существует ли элемент в массиве не уверен, ибо на php не пишу.